# CSS responsive design hide one column for small screens

Tags: css

Beginner to CSS here...

I am trying to update my site to a responsive 3 column layout.
I have used the code from www.responsivegridsystem.com/ and all is working well.
There is just one thing (for now!) I can't work out how to achieve.

At the moment the columns collapse under each other for very small screens which is great but I would like the third column (right) not to display at the same time as well.

Is this possible using  --  display: none; -- ?? If so, can someone suggest where exactly it should be placed to hide this column and not disturb anything else?
I have tried but can't see how to do this - I am not sure if it is even possible to do both collapse columns and hide one column in one media query.

Any help is much appreciated and apologies for my lack of knowledge.
See full page code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/PIngu123456/76Lkpna0/

```
.span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
```

Pingu

Comment: Like silviagreen said, use media queries. You have already used some in your code, so you should understand how they work. Here is a good resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks to all for your prompt and helpful replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify like this the last media query you have in your code

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                      #header {
                        height: auto;
                      }
                      h1 {
                        font-size: 24px;
                      }
                      #nav {
                        width auto
                      }
                      /* DIV STYLES ====================================================================== */
                      /* MARGINS */
                      #header,
                      #content {
                        margin-bottom: 5px;
                      }

                      .span_1_of_3:nth-of-type(3){ //this add your column
                        display: none;
                      }

                      }
```

This is the result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/76Lkpna0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do this using the `display` property. I updated your **JSfiddle** with the desired behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/76Lkpna0/1/

Code:

Add an extra class to the third column in **HTML**:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3 hidesmallscreen">
```

Add this **CSS** in the media query for small screens:

```
.hidesmallscreen {
                   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add an additional class to that column, such as `.last-col` or something. Then inside a media query, setting `display: none` for it under a specific width.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 500px) {
    .last-col {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Media queries are styles that will only be applied under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs all have the same class tag, `span_1_of_3`.  They should be named `span_1_of_3 span_2_of_3 span_3_of_3` so that you can give them separate styles.

You were using span_1_of_3 for all three divs, because that class is styled `width:32.26%` which gave you three columns.  In fact, span_2_of_3 was `width:66.13%` and span_3_of_3 was `width:100%`.  So change all three spans to `width:32.26%` to maintain your original format.

Then hide span_3_of_3 in your css, under `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {` by adding the following rule:

```
.span_3_of_3 {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Daniel,When I change the tags as you suggest, the column format is lost completely

Comment: I made the changes on your JSfiddle.  Works as you would like and allows you to further style each div.  The key is the 20+ lines just above the header  IMAGES.

Style each span to be `width: 32.26%`, then `display:none;` for span 3.

Comment: The answer you selected is not correctly using the responsive grid layout with three spans, and does not give you the ability to individually style them, as the layout was intended.

Comment: Sorry Daniel,I tried again to do as you suggest but the page column layout is completely destroyed. I can't tell you why.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I made an error in following your advice. I have retried exactly all of your steps and you are correct. Your solution works perfectly well too. So does Silviagreen's and pivemi's. Now I am unsure which suggestion is best...I have other pages to do as well. Maybe you could suggest why your suggestion is better. As I said, I used the column code from elsewhere and did not amend it; It is probably my failure to understand something. Pingu

Comment: It really doesn't matter.  All these solutions work.  You have it working and that is the important part.

The difference is that the original code was designed to give you individual style control of three spans.  By altering your code as I suggested, you have still have that capability while also getting the result you want.  It may be useful in the future, or maybe not.

Comment: While all solutions work, I'd recommend adding a seperate class above adding the pseudo selector :nth-of-type() to target the third column.  Using :nth-of-type() will mean that when you modify other columns classes, you may need to change the code that hides the third column as well. Using a seperate class for the column you want to hide doesn't have this problem. Also, in future, please consider upvoting the answers that you found helpful to your question. :-)